# Finding area of a region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let S be the part of plane $x+2y-z+5=0$ that lies inside cylinder $y^{2}+z^{2}-2y+4z-4=0$

Find the surface area of S

I know that I have to define a function that describes S (in terms of x,y,z) and then apply the integral of a surface area formula, but I don´t know how to do that. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rearrange $y^2+z^2−2y+4z−4=0$ to find a nice set of boundaries on the $yz$ plane. Use the method of completing a square.

> $(y-1)^2+(z+2)^2-9 = 0$.  A circle on the $yz$ plane centered at (0,1,-2) with r=3.

**Hint2:** Now what can you do with the next equation, $x+2y−z+5=0$? Specifically, how can you relate this to $S$?

Once you have that worked out, set up the integral $\iint \sqrt{f_y^2+f_z^2+1}dA$.

Comment: Why does the function that describe S does´t have a variable x? I know that I have to find a part of $x+2y−z+5=0$, but I don´t understand how to relate with S

Comment: So I'm assuming you've done a similar problem where you have a function $z=f(x,y)$ giving the "height" of a surface above the $xy$ plane. In this problem, we can use this same idea, but we'll do so using a region on the $yz$ plane with a height $x = f(y,z) = z-2y-5$ above it.

Comment: Or, in other words $S$ is the surface above the circle $(y−1)^2+(z+2)^2-9=0$ whose height at each point is given by $x=f(y,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

the cylinder is given by $(y-1)^2 + (z+2)^2 = 3^2$ we can parametrize this as $$y = 1 + \cos t, z = -2 + \sin t, 0 < t < 2\pi. $$  the plane $x = -2y +z - 5$ cuts the cylinder at the ellipse $$x = -2(1+\cos t) + (-2+\sin t) - 5 =-2\cos t+\sin t-9 = \sqrt 5\sin(t-b) - 9, b = \tan^{-1}( 2).$$ this is an ellipse with major axis $\sqrt{14}$ and minor axis $3,$  therefore the area is $$3\sqrt{14}\pi.$$